# How to make canvas background draggable and move within canvas using fabrics.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is it possible to drag canvas background using fabrics.js library? I want to drag canvas background image but i am unable to apply any method method on canvas to perform the same.

i have to set canvas background using the following code:

```
var imgsrc = 'gallery/pic1.jpg';
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(imgsrc,
        canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
           height:canvas.height,
           width:canvas.width,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,           
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
```

The above code is set background on canvas but it doesn't allow to drag background  on canvas criteria.

Comment: I don't think you can do like that. But you can add the image as a normal `fabric.Image` by remove the controls and borders from it setting `hasBorders` and `hasControls` to `false`. However make sure the image stays at the bottom of the layer stack to make it work like a background.

Answer (score 0):

try this after rendering the image:

`var objects = canvas.getObjects();
objects[0].selectable = true;
canvas.renderAll();`

Hope that helps